# Basic Javascript functions

Tags: javascript

I am just starting to learn programming and I am learning through codeacademy.com but I am stuck on this problem that they gave me. When I input this function like they told me to it gives me a syntax error. Any help is appreciated

```
// Write your foodDemand function below.
// Last hint: In your reusable block of code, end each line
// with a semicolon (;)
var foodDemand = Function("food"); {
    console.log ("I want to eat" + " " + food);
};
foodDemand ("Pizza");
```

Comment: Your answer already in here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname

Comment: Learn from this. https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/07/06/function-declarations-vs-function-expressions/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you meant to write `var foodDemand = function(food){...}` without quotes around "food".  Otherwise, in your  `console.log` you're passing in a variable, food, that has not been defined.

Answer (score -1):

Your syntax is wrong. Check some documentation about functions in JavaScript: 
[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions)